# Python2: iterable inside sum inside list inside class causes error

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, list-comprehension

The following code

```
class Foo:
    bar=[sum( i^j for i in range(9) )for j in range(9)]
```

raises

> ```
> NameError: global name 'j' is not defined
> ```

on my Python 2.7.14 IDLE, as well as an online interpreter.

If I understand correctly, `sum` accepts iterable as input. **What is going wrong?**

PS.

- If I use `sum([ ... ])` instead there will be no error.
- If I remove the outer list there will be no error.
- If the second line is executed outside class there will be no error.
- Python3 (in particular my 3.4.2 IDLE) does not raise error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue18110) with Python 2:

> In Python 2, list comprehensions don't have their own scope, so the x
>   in your initial example lives at class scope. However, the set
>   comprehension does have its own scope. By design, a variable defined
>   at class scope is not visible to inner scopes inside that class.
>
> In Python 3, this works because the list comprehension has its own
>   scope.

The example given was:

```
class Sudoku(dict):
    COLUMNS = [
        {(x, y) for y in xrange(9)} for x in xrange(9)}
    ]
```

Comment: Interesting. In your link, Eric said ***Nor does using `set`*** but it does on my machine. I do not understand...

Comment: Despite that, I understand what he said. (Although it is quite unsatisfied) Thank you for your quick response.